# Passing Command-Line Args to Function Using Splat Not Functioning as Expected in Powershell 2

Tags: powershell

Passing command-line arguments to a function using splat is not functioning as I would expect in Powershell 2.0.  I'm certain this is user error, but I haven't been able to find the resolution.

In a nutshell, I'm attempting to pass parameters specified on the command-line
directly to a function, once I've extracted the global parameters for the
script.  The following script is my MCVE of the issue I'm seeing:

```
# Named parameters.
Param([switch]$Foo)
# Function
function my_function {
    Param(
        [string]$Bar,
        [string]$Baz,
        [string]$Bat
    )
    Write-Output "==========="
    Write-Output "Value of function parameters:"
    Write-Output $Bar
    Write-Output $Baz
    Write-Output $Bat
    Write-Output "==========="
}
Write-Output "==========="
Write-Output "Value of `$args:"
Write-Output $args
Write-Output "==========="
my_function @args
$h = @{ Bar=0; Baz=1; Bat=2 }
my_function @h
```

My output is:

```
PS C:\temp> .\test-script -Bar 0 -Baz 1 -Bat 2
===========
Value of $args:
-Bar
0
-Baz
1
-Bat
2
===========
===========
Value of function parameters:
-Bar
0
-Baz
===========
===========
Value of function parameters:
0
1
2
===========
PS C:\temp>
```

Based on my understanding of the `splat` feature, the two `Value of function parameters` sections should look identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx):

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can also use splatting to represent all parameters of a command.

Comment: I see it now.  I read through the docs multiple times when I was trying to figure this out, kept looking right past that little gem.

Comment: Splatting is a v2 feature, but the particular splatting functionality you're trying to use was added with v3.